# Type in a data validation cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using data validation to offer a list of choice for each cell in a column. Is there a way to make it possible to type in each cell, rather than have to select from the drop down list?

The drop down list is quite long so would like to search it.

Answer (score 0):

The default setting when a data validation dropdown list is created is to allow the user to type in the cell as well. Is this an active-x control dropdown or just a dropdown in the cells?

If it is just in the cells, then select the cell, go to Data-> Data Validation -> Validation -> then unselect the checkbox that says select from drop-down list.

If it is a VBA control, it would have to be replaced with an inputbox both in the sheet and in the code.

Comment: Sorry @Kory I really meant that I would like to type and get autocompletion in the dropdown. It is a dropdown in the cell.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry. I do not know how to do this off the top of my head. It can most likely be done with some VBA that triggers once you type a letter into the cell, but that could end up being very slow for the user.